# JSP changes not reflecting in JBOSS7.2 after restart(after clearing server and browser cache)

Tags: java, jsp, jboss7.x

I am facing a problem that changes done in JSP file is not reflecting in generated java and class files in tmp path (/standalone/tmp/my.ear.myWeb.war/org/apache/jsp/App_UI/).

I followed the steps as below

- Changed in JSP file
- Stopped JBOSS process
- Deployed in my ear(I am exploded form. So directly replaced)
- Cleared JBOSS cache file (data, tmp, log) under standalone directory
- Restarted the jboss process

Ear directory structure $AppHome/my.ear/myWeb.war/App_UI/ and there are other webservices war present parallel to myWeb.war.

After restart when access the application page which execute the jsp, still showing old page content. When I look at tmp directory in path '$JbossHOME/standalone/tmp/my.ear.myWeb.war/org/apache/jsp/App_UI/' java and class files are in older dates like below

-rw-r--r-- 1 user user **170243 Feb 10  2022** BeneficieryMaster_005_jsp.java

-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  **53925 Feb 10  2022** BeneficieryMaster_005_jsp.class

-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   **8408 Aug 4 2022** BeneficieryMaster_005_005fTable_jsp.java

-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   **6939 Aug 4  2022** BeneficieryMaster_005_005fTable_jsp.class

As process is restarted, all files to be recompiled by JBOSS and reflect in tmp directory. But it is not happening. Also no errors in server logs and applications logs.

Could not find the cause for last 3 days. Any pointer will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After long analysis found that the issue is due to caching at HA Proxy (external layer at infra level). After clearing it, it worked.

We also understand that the caching can be at Web layer, Proxy and LB. So caching before application layer will cause similar problem.

I have added our finding here which might be helpful to someone.